# How to overcome change of position in Listview in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter, radix

In Base adapter there contains maultiple views along with checkbox,

If i select check box , one position is getting, and if i scroll and unselect the same checkbox, someother position is getting, but i need same position.. how to get this?

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing any code.. it could be a problem with getView method

Comment: Reffer API Demos (Views/Lists/Multiple Choice List).Best Example ever.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your adapter is recycling views and you are not handling it properly. Make sure you are using `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` or `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)`

If you are using custom list items, please refer to my tutorial: [CUSTOM LISTVIEW WITH ABILITY TO CHECK ITEMS](http://blog.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/)

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class

```
 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
if (row == null) 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reports_list, null);
}

CheckBox cBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.cb1);

cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(cBox.isChecked())
    {
       System.out.println("position "+reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox));
    }
}
});
```